# Fetch external data from class constructor Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a User class with one constructor variable "id" and i want to fetch some user data from an external source, but i also need to await the object creation until i get those data. I tried to declare an async function inside the constructor and await the data there, but it does not pause the execution to fetch the data, so it returns undefined.

Comment: Your constructor should not have dependencies on external resources and it should not cause side effects. Create a separate `init` method to evaluate properties depending on external resources.

Comment: if you really want instance creation after you have all the required data, try using an async factory method